# SIMPLE SQL QUERY RETURNING Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: sql, terminal, mariadb

Good afternoon, I have searched the interwebs for hours in regards to this error message I am receiving in MariaDB and have yet to find an answer. I am attempting to add another date into a varchar(255) column and it keeps returning

`Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2022-10-14'`

The sql query I have been using is

`UPDATE communities SET lastvisited = '2022-10-14' + lastvisited WHERE id = 26;`

Its a very simple query I am doing and I am not using `AND` or `ON` so very confused why it keeps returning that message. Thank you

Comment: What's the value of lastvisited?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to add date values to a varchar? *Is* `lastvisited` a varchar? What's the length of the data existing in the column? This *sounds* like you're violating first-normal form...

Comment: Because datetime column type does not allow multiple dates, the column length is 9 characters. I have the table working perfectly right now with adding a singular date to the column but I am attempting to add multiple dates to the one column.

Comment: The value of lastvisited is '2022-10-11'

Comment: *datetime column type does not allow multiple dates* - you're using a *relational* database management system. Storing multiple values in a single column is a common anti-pattern, store each date in its own row - then, for example, counting how many you have, the difference between first and last etc, are all trival problems that become unecessarily hard by doing what (I assume) you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is an arithmetic operator. That means, all parts of an arithmetic operation will be converted to int or double before the operation will be performed:

If you specify a string, it should be convertible either to  a double or integer - if there are special chars, it will be truncated an a warning will be raised:

"2022-10-14" is a string, it is not an arithmetic operation with the result 2022 - 10 - 14 = 1998. So converting "2022-10-14" to a number will always result in 2022, since - within a number is invalid:

```
select CAST("2022-10-14" as INTEGER)
+-------------------------------+
| cast("2022-10-14" as integer) |
+-------------------------------+
|                          2022 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,001 sec)

show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                         |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '2022-10-14' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

That is the explanation for the warning.

I don't have a crystal ball, so I don't know (and to be honest "don't understand") which value you expect after updating. Is it "2022-10-142022-10-11"? In this case use concat() function. If you want to perform an arithmetic operation like 2022 - 10 - 14 + 2022 - 10 - 11 use YEAR, MONTH and DAY functions. If you want add dates use DATE_ADD.

Comment: Makes so much sense! Thank you so much :)